# How could I connect my Eclipse IDE with the Oralce 11g in Windows 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle11g

I want my java program to handle Oracle SQL queries. For that, I have written the following code.

[image]

on running this code it shows the following errors.

[image]

I don't know how to connect my Eclipse IDE with the Oracle. How could I connect my Eclipse IDE to the Oracle and how to get rid of these errors? And I don't want to connect to any online oracle servers, I googled and get suggestions for connecting to online servers.

How could I connect my Oracle 11g with my Eclipse Kepler in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below :

1. Driver version and DB version should be same.
2. Try login with `sqlplus` or some clients like Toad, SQL developer.
3. The number of connections allowed may exceeded, result in TNS listener error, that you may got minus one from read call error in stacktrace. If connections are exceeded kill inactive connections.

Try establishing connection like below

```
DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

Comment: How do I check the versions of Driver and DB?
And how could I change the number of connections in either sql plus or Oracle 11g GUI based window?

Comment: server version will get printed in cmd prompt after successful authentication, check both the server and driver are same version, google it to increase connection

Answer (score 0):

Above exception your are getting when operating system has some internal environment problem.

I have got same problem with type 4 driver. But type 1 driver not giving this exception. So start using the type 1 oracle driver.

You can check the sid port in tnsnames.ora file which is in below location.

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN\SAMPLE\tnsnames.ora